# In the Hammond / Harney County land-use situation, what precedents does the BLM act on to restrict landowners?

Tags: real-estate, environmental, agriculture

I have read a number of accounts of the details involved, most of which [resemble this one, and are biased against the BLM](http://theconservativetreehouse.com/2016/01/03/full-story-on-whats-going-on-in-oregon-militia-take-over-malheur-national-wildlife-refuge-in-protest-to-hammond-family-persecution/).  I have yet to find information on what position the BLM took in changing the land-use in that area.

The primary cause of arresting the landowners involves seems to be [a claim of arson](http://www.justice.gov/usao-or/pr/eastern-oregon-ranchers-convicted-arson-resentenced-five-years-prison), but I am asking about the land-use dynamics that constructed the relationship between landowners and federal/state government parties.

Does anyone have a picture of the facets of this situation?

In a DOI / BLM land use situation, what precedents exist for similar regional initiatives?

Comment: I'm trying to best formulate a valuable question; please suggest edits.